# Coorddinate system described by following 2D change of variables

Tags: coordinate-systems, change-of-variable

I found following change of variables that can be also seen as a coordinate system $(y_1, y_2)$ described according to cartesian coordinates $(x_1, x_2)$:

$$y_1 = x_1 · (1+(x_1-1)\sin(\frac{\pi x_2}{2}))$$
$$y_2 = \frac{1}{ 1+(x_1-1)\sin(\frac{\pi x_2}{2})}$$

but do not match any of the common ones (polar, parabolic, hyperbolic, elliptic, bipolar...). I am interested in its name (if exists) in order to search for further info, uses...

Comment: For clarity, is the square applied to the logarithm itself, or is it applied only to $x_i$?

Comment: To whole logarithm, if not could be simplified